# How to increase speed of emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-emulator, ram

I have 1 gb `RAM` in my pc. First when i am creating `AVD` with `RAM` size 512 in `Eclipse`. Then start emulator its speed very slow and on running application its showing message your `RAM` size compressed to 348. Then i deleted this AVD and created new one with `RAM` 256. Its work bit faster than the earlier one but still slow speed. And whenever i close `AVD` its show stop responding message and close after some time. I am using `3.2" QVGA(ADP2)(320*480:mdpi)` `AVD` with target `Android:4.2.2-API Level 17`. I choose snapshot option. I have seen lots of question regarding this but most of the answers said this is not related to system `RAM`.

Please if someone know how to solve this problem and increase the speed of emulator help me.

I've not seen the link provided by simon before asking this question. yes it is duplicate. Thank you simon for providing me that link and your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know is to set CPU as Intel Atom (x86) if You working on Windows.

That's because x86 and Windows use more or less the same architecture and emulator don't have to emulate architecture

Comment: yes i am using windows and x86. But your answer is not very clear its hard to understand for me. can you please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

if you are using pc with intel processor
download the latest intel x86 atom system image from SDK manager( see screenshot) and create new avd with this option ...

otherwise i suggest you to use "genymotion" which is virtual device like emulator and it's very fast .. try once.

Comment: Any link regarding geny motion?

Comment: yea sure... http://www.genymotion.com/ 
and for downloading it https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

Comment: if you found any issue regarding installing and working on it... let me know

Comment: any link that explain me about steps involved in above screen shot? And gennymotion is paid one?

Comment: you can open SDK manager from eclipse and by opening SDk manager, this screen will open.. it will fetch data from internet automatically.

Comment: You have to check the option for Intel x86 for your SDK version and download it. After that you can create new avd from Intel system image...

Comment: And i am usin genymotion and its totally free...

Answer (score 2):

I found the following:

1. When setting up the AVD, for **CPU/ABI** choose **intel Atom (x86)**
2. On the same page check the box **Use Host GPU**
3. When starting the AVD, look for this in the pop-up with the progress bar:

   ```
   emulator: device fd:964
   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
   creating window 0 0 270 480
   ```

If you get an error about HAXM not working, go to: [Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager 1.0.6 (R3)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), extract the InteHaxm.exe file and move it to the sdk directory, (like `\sdk\extras\intel\`

For some reason, I was getting an error with the HAXM, and installing the Intel one solved it.

EDIT: You only have 1G RAM on your PC?  That's a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator is pretty slow because of the hardware accelerated UI.

On a real device, the rendering is performed using the device's GPU. The emulator, however, uses a software renderer to do that.

If I remember correctly, the UI rendering has been improved to use the GPU more in either Android 3.x or 4.x.

A couple of tips on increasing the emulator performance would be to use the Intel HAXM emulator (along with the intel Atom system images) and to try an use an older 2.x version of Android (2.x should run MUCH better in the emulator, compared to a 4.x).

Using this emulator speeds up the calls for the software rendering routines in the emulator and it can provide quite a bit of a boost.

If you can use an older version of Android (2.x), you should go for that. The performance is a lot better for that than for 4.x versions.

Note: The Intel HAXM emulator requires that you use an  OSX or Windows OS with an Intel processor.

Answer (score -3):

Use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. Emulator runs faster on it

Comment: If you know how to solve it on eclipse then answer me.

Comment: @JohnR - First of all, you didn't mentioned eclipse in your question so i am downvoting your question as well and secondly android studio is way much better and emulator runs quite fast in it

Comment: Revenge wow. keep going.

Comment: Dude i posted a correct answer. You downvoted it because you needed it only on eclipse. Did you try googling it ? Secondly, you have not mentioned eclipse in your question. So if you can downvote a correct answer, i can too. Thirdly it is a duplicate question. my reasons for downvoting are better

Comment: This answer is hilariously incorrect. The emulator is not built into android studio or eclipse and has no dependency to either, therefore the IDE you use has absolutely **NO** bearing on the performance of the emulation. The emulator is included in the android SDK (which is the same for both IDEs assuming you download the same platform tools).